# Open sets on the unit circle $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

While doing some Analysis 3 exercises, I came across the problem of showing that a function $f:S^1\to S^1$ is open, cts and surjective. Here I am thinking about $S^1$ as a metric subspace of the reals. I thought about using the function $(x,y)\mapsto(x^2-y^2,2xy)$, i.e. just squaring the corresponding complex number, but I'm not sure how to prove that this is open as I'm having trouble understanding the notion of open sets in this metric.

I've seen some solutions using sets like $I:=\{e^{it} | t∈(a,b)\}$, but I need help/an explanation as to why this is open and how open sets work in $S^1$ in general.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can see $S^1$ as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the quotient topology induced by the natural topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. From the standard point of view of topology, the *definition* of homeomorphism is a function that is open, continuous, and bijective. So it looks like you are implicitly assuming a different definition of homeomorphism. Your question could therefore be greatly improved by editing the question to include that definition.

Comment: Also, the squaring function is not bijective, so your intentions regarding that function are rather unclear as well.

Comment: Just edited a little bit. Since this function isn't bijective, I know that it should work as a counterexample for the homeomorphism part, but I just want to show that is it open first.

Comment: I still don't really understand the question. You need to construct a homeomorphism? Show that a given function is not a homeomorphism? Showing that a function is a homeomorphism if and only if it is bijective, continuous and open? If it is the last option, what is your definition of a homeomorphism?

Comment: Hi, sorry, another edit. Accidentally said bijective instead of surjective, but still, I just need help understanding what an open set in $S^1$ is in order to prove the openness of my fcn.

Comment: By definition a subset of $S^1$ is open if it is the intersection of an open subset of the plane with $S^1$. It turns out that the sets of the form $\{e^{it}|a<t<b\}$ (for some real $a,b$) form a basis of this topology. The proof shouldn't be hard, just a bit technical. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @freakish $(1,1)$ is not in $S^1$

Comment: The following is a trivial remark, which is possibly not what you need. But if you just need an example of a mapping of $S^1$ onto itself that is open, continuous and surjective, take the identity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach.

Let us first understand the topology on $S^1$.

The continuous map
$$\phi : \mathbb R \to S^1, \phi(t) = e^{it} =\cos t + i\sin t,$$
has the property
$$\phi(s) = \phi(t) \text{ iff }  s - t = 2\pi k \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb Z .\tag{*} $$
We have $\phi([0,2\pi]) = S^1$. Thus also $\phi([a,2\pi+a]) = S^1$ for each $a \in \mathbb R$. Consider an open interval $(a,b)$ and let $S^1(a,b) = \phi((a,b)) = \{ e^{it} \mid t\in (a,b) \}$.

1. If $b - a > 2\pi$, then $S^1(a,b) = S^1$ (which is trivially open in $S^1$).
2. If $b - a \le 2\pi$, then $S^1(a,b)$ is open in $S^1$: The set $K = [a,2\pi +a] \setminus (a,b)$ is compact, hence $\phi(K) \subset S^1$ is compact, thus closed in $S^1$. Therefore $S^1 \setminus \phi(K)$ is open in $S^1$.  We have $S^1 = \phi([a,2\pi +a]) = \phi(K \cup (a,b)) = \phi(K) \cup \phi((a,b))$. But $K$ and $(a,b)$ are disjoint, thus $s \in K$ and $t \in (a,b)$ cannot have the same image under $\phi$ (note that by (*) the only two distinct points in $[a,2\pi +a]$ having the same image under $\phi$ are $a$ and $2\pi + a$). We conclude that $\phi(K)$ and $ \phi((a,b))$ are disjoint, hence $\phi((a,b)) = S^1 \setminus \phi(K)$.
3. $\phi$ is an open map: Each open $U \subset \mathbb R$ can be written as $U = \bigcup_{t \in U}(t-r(t),t+r(t))$ with suitable $r(t) > 0$. Thus $\phi(U) = \bigcup_{t \in U}\phi((t-r(t),t+r(t)))$ is open in $S^1$.
4. If $b - a \le 2\pi$, then the restriction $\phi_{a,b} : (a,b) \to \phi((a,b)) = S^1(a,b)$ of $\phi$ is a homeomorphism: By (*) it is a bijection, by 3. it is an open map.
5. The sets $S^1(a,b)$ form a basis for the topology on $S^1$: Let $V \subset S^1$ be open and $z_0 \in V$. There is $t_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $\phi(t_0) = z_0$. Then $\phi^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ containing $t_0$. There exists $r > 0$ such that $(t_0 -r t_0 +r) \subset \phi^{-1}(V)$. Hence $z_0 \in \phi((t_0 -r t_0 +r)) \subset V$.

Let us now show that $f$ is an open map.

It suffices to show that the images of the basis elements $S^1(a,b)$ are open in $S^1$. But
$$f(S^1(a,b)) = f(\{ e^{it} \mid t\in (a,b) \}) = \{ e^{2it} \mid t\in (a,b) \} = \{ e^{is} \mid s \in (2a,2b) \} = S^1(2a,2b) .$$

Answer (score 1):

I shall use a little piece of complex analysis:

> Each non-constant holomorphic map $\phi : U \to \mathbb C$  defined on an open $U \subset \mathbb C$ is an open map.

Hence the map $F : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, F(z) = z^2$, is an open map. Its restriction to $S^1$ yields your map $f$.

Let $V \subset S^1$ be open. There exists an open $V' \subset \mathbb C$ such that $V' \cap S^1 = V$. Thus $W = F(V') \cap S^1$ is open in $S^1$. We claim $W = f(V)$ which will prove that $f$ is an open map.

1. $f(V) = F(V) \subset F(V')$. Since trivially $f(V) \subset S^1$, we get $f(V) \subset W$.
2. For each $w \in W = F(V') \cap S^1$ there exists $z \in V'$ such that $F(z) = w$. We have $\lvert z \rvert^2 = \lvert z^2 \rvert = \lvert w \rvert = 1$, thus $\lvert z \rvert = 1$ and therefore $z \in V' \cap S^1 = V$. We have $f(z) = F(z) = w$. Thus $W \subset f(V)$.

We can also use the above result about holomorphic maps to prove that the map
$$\phi : \mathbb R \to S^1, \phi(t) = e^{it},$$
(which is a surjection) is an open map. In fact $f(z) = e^z$ is a non-constant holomorphic map, thus an open map. If $W \subset \mathbb R$ is open, then $W' = \mathbb R \times W$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb C$, hence $f(W')$ is open in $\mathbb C$. We have
$$f(W') = \{ e^xe^{iy} \mid x \in \mathbb R, y \in W \} .$$
But $e^xe^{iy} \in S^1$ iff $e^x = 1$, thus
$$f(W') \cap S^1 = \{ e^{iy} \mid y \in W \} = \phi(W) .$$
This shows in particular that all sets
$$S^1(a,b) = \{ e^{iy} \mid y \in (a,b) \} = \phi((a,b))$$
are open in $S^1$. Moreover, they from a *basis* for the topology on $S^1$. In fact, let $U \subset S^1$ be open and $z_0 \in U$. There is $t_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $\phi(t_0) = z_0$. Since $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb R$ and contains $t_0$, we find $r > 0$ such that $(t_0-r, t_0+r) \subset  \phi^{-1}(U)$. This shows $z_0 \in \phi((t_0-r, t_0+r)) \subset U$.

Let us finally note that

1. If $b -a > 2\pi$, then $S^1(a,b) = S^1$.
2. If $b -a \le 2\pi$, then the resriction $\phi_{a,b} : (a,b) \to S^1(a,b)$ is a homeomorphism. To see that, note that $\phi_{a,b}$ is a bijection which is open.