# $\psi:(0;2\pi)\rightarrow S^1 -\{(1;0)\}; \ \alpha\mapsto(\cos(\alpha);\sin(\alpha))$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

I need to show that $S^1$ is smooth manifold with the Following structure

$$
U=\{(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha): \alpha \in(0,2 \pi)\}, \quad V=\{(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha): \alpha \in(-\pi, \pi)\} .
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\varphi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad \varphi(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)=\alpha, \quad \alpha \in(0,2 \pi) \\
&\psi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad \psi(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)=\alpha, \quad \alpha \in(-\pi, \pi)
\end{aligned}
$$

I've managed to show that the maps :

$$f:(0;2\pi)\rightarrow  S^1 -\{(1;0)\}; \ \alpha\mapsto(\cos(\alpha);\sin(\alpha))$$
and

$$g:(-\pi;\pi)\rightarrow  S^1 -\{(-1;0)\}; \ \alpha\mapsto(\cos(\alpha);\sin(\alpha))$$

are bijection; and it is clear that they are continuous (the coordinates functions are continuous) . But how do we show the inverse is also continous??

any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ has the subspace topology, so open sets are given by $U \cap S^1$ where $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So given an open interval $(a,b)$ can you express $f(a,b) \in S^1$ in this form, hence showing that $(a,b)$ open $\implies f(a,b) = (f^{-1})^{-1}(a,b)$ open i.e. that $f^{-1}$ continuous

Comment: The map $\phi : \mathbb R \to S^1,  \phi(t) = e^{it} = \cos t + i \sin t$, is open which proves that $f$ and $g$ are open maps. See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3873485.

Comment: thank you all. for @Dylan : is the open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is gonna be what is above the line passing through the two points $(cos(a),sin(a))$ and $(cos(b),sin(b))$??

Comment: @PaulFrost Im looking into it , thak your sir.

Comment: @DonnieDarko Sorry, I didn't see this notification. Well above is not the word I would use, but the open set in $S^1$ will be the arc of the circle between $(\cos(a),\sin(a))$ and $(\cos(b),\sin(b))$. The open sets are what you would expect, visually they look like arced open intervals of the real line, if that helps.

Comment: Although $S^1$ is a smooth manifold, the question has nothing to do with smooth structures. It is a general topology question. I suggest to edit the tags.